# Is it possible to set Auto fit for Graphics with BIRT?

Tags: layout, graph, birt

Is it possible to set Auto fit for Graphics?

I tried to delete Width and Height but it did not give me the behavior I would like. When I delete Width and Height for table, it's working but not for graphics. I put 'Auto Layout' in the layout prefenrence, but nothing seems working.

For example, I have one Area, and I would like to have the maximum width size when the user is using the web viewer or the preview.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have a 'auto' width but not height by addind a grid (with no height and no width), inside put the graphic and set the page as autofit.

This is the best solution I found... if someone have anything else...